# XML Doctype, how to apply

Tags: xml, xsd, doctype

How do I apply a doctype in xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE application [
       <!ELEMENT application (#PCDATA)>
]>
<application>
       <settings>
              <environment use="production" />
              <database datasource="MySQL" environment="production" />
              <database datasource="MySQL" environment="development" />
              <import>
                     <path value="Application" />
                     <path value="Application/Library" />
              </import>
       </settings>
       <environment name="production">
              <database>
                     <hostname value="127.0.0.1" />
                     <username value="root" />
                     <password value="" />
                     <database value="app" />
              </database>
       </environment>
       <environment name="development">
              <database>
                     <hostname value="127.0.0.1" />
                     <username value="root" />
                     <password value="" />
                     <database value="app" />
              </database>
       </environment>
</application>
```

I also wanted to validate the elements that are necessary to contain and attributes in the XML, for example, environment settings, you must have this node, and also how I can create a single doctype that can be implemented by various XML, so how can I validate xml using xsd file?

Comment: DOCTYPE declarations are used with DTDs. But you also mention validation using xsd file, which usually means a W3C XML Schema. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, w3c schema .. just want to know even how do you apply a dtd for all xmls

Comment: Are you using both XML Schema and DTD? These are two different schema languages.

Comment: No, I'm using dtd .. but I would like to validate these attributes with xsd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following schema (you need to populate the type definitions):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://example.com/sample"
    xmlns="http://example.com/sample">
  <xs:element name="application">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="settings" type="settingsType" />
        <xs:element name="environment" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="environmentType" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <!-- type definitions -->
  <xs:complexType name="settingsType">
    ... define type here...
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="environmentType">
    ... define type here...
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The XML instance you wish to validate can then be associated with the schema by including a xmlns attribute in your root node:

```
<application xmlns="http://example.com/sample">
       <settings>
              ....
       </settings>
       <environment name="production">
              ....
       </environment>
       <environment name="development">
              ....
       </environment>
</application>
```

Comment: I have one other question, in settings, there will be a node that contains the definition of environment which will be used, if so, how could I verify that this environment exists in the xml?

Comment: Based on the schema in my answer above a conforming XML document must have at least one *environment* node, otherwise this will not validate against the schema. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Nopz, check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511736/xsd-restricted-rule and you understand what i trying to do.

Comment: OK I see what you mean. Well you can extend an XSD simple type (string etc) to use an XSD restriction based on an enumeration but this enumeration is contained within the definition of your type, and cannot be pulled in from outside that definition, so you may have a problem there.

Comment: Has any way to check this definition ?