# How check file XML

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest, linq-to-xml

I have xml file. I think file is not correct.I check file in validator. I get link: http://validator.w3.org. I get 3 warinngs but document is good. My question is that file correct.Do I must add DOCTYPE. Can you help me.I am green in XML. Can you give me tutorial, books, article, blog about xml.

```
<xs:element name="itemsList">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="item" type="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="item">
    <xs:attribute name="weight" type="weight" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="weightUnit" type="weightUnit" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="volume" type="volume" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="volumeUnit" type="volumeUnit" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="remarks" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="uld">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="item" type="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="uldType" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="capacity" type="volume" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="volumeUnit" type="volumeUnit" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="maxWeight" type="weight" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="weightUnit" type="weightUnit" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:simpleType name="weightUnit">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="kg"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="volumeUnit">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="m3"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="uldType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{3}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="weight">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:float">
        <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="volume">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:float">
        <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you get '3 warning but page is good'. What were the 3 warnings you got? Yes, you do need your doctype to validate effectively.

Here is a version of your code that validates. It includes the Schema, and the encoding. It validates just fine.

As far as the DOCTYPE is concerned, I suggest you do some reading and get your learn on as it can be fairly specific. Here are some links to point you in the right direction:

http://www.sitepoint.com/xml-dtds-xml-schema/

[XML Doctype, how to apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507549/xml-doctype-how-to-apply)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="itemsList">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="item" type="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="item">
    <xs:attribute name="weight" type="weight" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="weightUnit" type="weightUnit" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="volume" type="volume" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="volumeUnit" type="volumeUnit" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="remarks" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="uld">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="item" type="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="uldType" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="capacity" type="volume" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="volumeUnit" type="volumeUnit" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="maxWeight" type="weight" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="weightUnit" type="weightUnit" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:simpleType name="weightUnit">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="kg"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="volumeUnit">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="m3"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="uldType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{3}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="weight">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:float">
        <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="volume">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:float">
        <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: 1) No DOCTYPE found! Checking XML syntax only. 2)No Character encoding declared at document level. 3)Using Direct Input mode: UTF-8 character encoding assumed.

Comment: Aye, so it's saying you're missing the doctype, which includes the character encoding. You need the doctype.

Comment: What character encoding use. It can be e.g UTF-8.I do not understand.In which line add doctype.

Comment: I must read xml course. Then I now in which line add doctype.